# ESLint: Possible race condition: `user.registered` might be reassigned based on an outdated value of `user.registered`. (require-atomic-updates)

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, eslint

I have created an async function as below:

```
let createUserWrapper = async function(user){
                await Log.createUser(user);
                if (!user.registered) {
                    user.registered = true;
                    //userToSave has been declared outside of this function's scope
                    userToSave = true;
                }
            };
```

The line `user.registered = true;` seems to show the warning under the `user` object. I am not understanding why this shows, since whatever happens above in the await, we pass objects by reference so we have the latest value of the `registered` key when the code continues.

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/require-atomic-updates

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar My code is not affected by the example, since I am awaiting first and then continuing with my code execution.

Comment: @Ncifra the eslint example also awaits inside the function, but eslint warns you that createUserWrapper might be called twice with the same user in a non-awaited context.

Comment: @hraban what error code is it? I don't remember having another warning, but maybe I had those rules disabled at the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a false positive. ESLint is assuming that the `await Log.createUser(user);` line is manipulating the `user` object data, so if we were to have in parallel another async function similar to the above, like:

```
let createUserWrapper2 = async function(user){
                await Log.createUser2(user);
                if (!user.registered) {
                    user.registered = true;
                    //userToSave has been declared outside of this function's scope
                    userToSave = true;
                }
            };
```

and then execute:

```
Promise.all([createUserWrapper(user), createUserWrapper2(user)]).then(() => {
...
});
```

Considering the parallel execution in Promise.all(), the value of user.registered in each of the two functions, may not be the value from the latest value, but the old one from the "own" async function. I still think that it is a bit messy, and can't quite point out what it is supposed to show, considering that the execution is linear, and the objects are passed by reference, so each execution tick will have the latest object data.

Comment: It's a shame JavaScript doesn't have constant parameters to make solving this ambiguity easier.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
user.registered = false;
let createUserWrapper = async function(user){
  await Log.createUser(user);
  if (!user.registered) { // registered value from createUser(user)
      user.registered = true;
      //userToSave has been declared outside of this function's scope
      userToSave = true;
  }
};
```

Comment: The problem is that I have to read the actual value, since it is existing, I can't just set it manually. Nonetheless, I tried it but the warning still shows.

Comment: Yes, it will read the actual value that you get from Log.createUser(user) // I hope this function returns user's registered value.

Comment: But user.registered can also be existing and true even before createUser, so that's why I can't set it beforehand.